# How to get class value of a clicked element and use this value to put a piece of html code after the last occurance of this class in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an element

```
<div class="item cars column-2 row-1">
Mercedes
</div>
```

And I want to get the value after `row-`. In this case it would be 1.

My code so far:

```
$(function() {
    $( ".item" ).click(function() {
      $('.detail-description-catcher').empty();
      $(this).find('.description').clone().appendTo('.detail-description-catcher').show();
    });
});
```

The display part is an empty div:

```
<div class="detail-description-catcher"><!-- --></div>
```

My goal is to show the description of an element after a click. This is OK and I know how to do that.

The problematic part is how to detect where to put the `<div class="detail-description-catcher"><!-- --></div>` code part.

So, I need to **get the value of `row-`** e.g. row-1 or row-2 and then **find the last occurence of this class** (this is defined in php, usually it increments after 4 solumns, but I need to be dynamic in jquery) and **put the detail-description-catcher div after this element.**

Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$(function () {
    var $ddc = $('.detail-description-catcher');
    $(".item").click(function () {
        $ddc.empty();
        //here num will be 1
        var num = this.className.match(/row-(\d+)/)[1];
        $(this).find('.description').clone().appendTo($ddc).show();
        $ddc.insertAfter($('.item.row-' + num).last())
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/23zWK/)

Also

```
$(function () {
    var $ddc = $('.detail-description-catcher');
    $(".item").click(function () {
        $ddc.empty();
        var clazz = this.className.match(/\b(row-\d+)\b/)[1];
        $(this).find('.description').clone().appendTo($ddc).show();
        $ddc.insertAfter($('.item.' + clazz).last())
    });
});
```